# Securely connect to a database from a CLI

Tags: postgresql, kotlin, heroku, heroku-postgres

I am writing a CLI in **Kotlin** primarily using this library: the [CLIKT Library](https://ajalt.github.io/clikt/) and I am using **Gradle** to manage dependencies

I have a separate **Django** website that I have deployed to **Heroku**

This **Heroku** app has a `heroku-postgresql` add-on (Not sure if this is relevant: I haven't configured or populated the `postgresql` database)

I want the CLI to *securely connect* to the database and read some **JSON** from it

My goal is to distribute the CLI through the **Django** website (I'm mentioning this because I want you to know that the CLI will be available to anyone which is why I need it to securely connect to the database)

Comment: "*I want the CLI to be available to anyone*" - then whom do you want to secure your database against? It sounds like you want everyone to be able to connect to and use your database, in which case there is no need to secure it.

Comment: I wasn't sure of the best way to phrase it. I want anyone to be able to connect and access data but not modify. And when I said "secure", I meant that I wasn't sure of the best way to store credentials. For example, when I deployed my Heroku app, I was able to setup my SECRET_KEY into an environment variable. I don't know of the best way to do that with things like my database URL

Comment: You don't, then. Putting the credentials to your database in the cli application that you distribute gives everyone those credentials. You could create a restricted database user that has only `SELECT` permissions on the relevant tables/columns, and make the credentials for that public, but it would still allow people to DOS-attack your database. The established approach is to build a HTTP API in your web application, and contact that from your cli application. It might be completely open or secured using http auth, but you at least control the SQL.